# Are there any differences in how Python handles Unicode on different platforms?

Tags: python, unicode

This is not a specific but rather a general question: are there any differences in how Python handles Unicode on different platforms?

I use Python 3 to read a text file. The following code opens a file and skips the first row:

```
fin = open(filename, 'rt')
next(fin)
```

I run the same code on a Linux computer and on Mac. I use conda environment that was created using the same `environment.yml` file. I also verified that I use the same Python version on both the computers (Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.). The data file is fetched from the same Git repository. For some reason, the Linux version raises an exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Things to check: that you're really using Python 3 and what does [`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) give you on the platform where it fails. "In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding." Since it'd seem you control the data file, pick an encoding to use and explicitly pass it to `open()` when you open it.

Comment: `explicit is better than implicit`.  When dealing with text files, a good BKM is to always specify the encoding in `open`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The encoding doesn't depend on python but on your LOCALE variables.

It is likely that you are not using a UTF-8 locale. You can check which locale python is using with

```
import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))'
```

which on your Mac should return `UTF-8`, while on your linux system something like `US-ASCII`

**How to fix it?**

On Most system, the locale is taken from *environment variables* (see [the POSIX locale documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html)

Adding `LC_ALL=en.UTF-8` to your `.bash_profile` or equivalent will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [the python3 docs for the open() builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> ... In text mode ... the contents of the file are returned as `str`, the bytes having been first decocded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the specified *encoding* if given ... The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) returns)...

Are you sure that the preferred encoding reported by the locale lib is the same on both platforms? You can enforce the encoding for reading from text files like this:

```
fin = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
next(fin)
```

Note that you don't need the file mode `rt`, as the `t` is assumed for basic file read modes; in fact, you don't need `r` either, as it's the default mode. So you can just do this, if you like:

```
fin = open(filename, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: `'r'` is the default and it isn't needed either :^)

Comment: nice -- answer amended!